# why enabling CORS for js files by setting crossorigin= anonymous cause “blocked by CORS policy” although Access-Control-Allow-Origin exist?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cors

We wanted to have error information for the js scripts being loaded from different domains.
Based on documents we have set crossorigin= "anonymous" attribute on script tags  and we are sending Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* from our js servers with another domain but in some users not all chrome blocks loading script files why is that happening?

Script tag in main html page from first domain domain:

```
script type='text/javascript' src='myseconddomain.com/testscript.js' crossOrigin='anonymous'></script
```

and response header for testscript.js has "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*"

Comment: please provide some code.

Comment: Is there a blank present in the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone yes here is my bad typing but in actual response header there is a blank, and it is working in many cases but we had some blocked

Comment: Another issue *might* be, that `type='text/javascript'` is depricated. The mimetype should be `application/javascript` now. Your problem seems to be some useragent implementation.

Comment: This might be interesting for you as well: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=387198

Answer (score 2):

seems chrome has a a problem of caching javascript files without looking at their  crossOrigin attributes meaning if there is a js file refereed in the page without crossOrigin attribute and later you edit and add this attribute chrome ignore it and use its cached version which causes problems